# Why does gcc -Wdiscarded-qualifiers complain about this code?

Tags: c, gcc, qsort, const-correctness, qualifiers

I were writing a `qsort` compare function callback for this scenario:

```c
int matrix[3][4] = 
{
  {1,2,3,4},
  {5,6,7,8},
  {9,1,2,3},
};

qsort(matrix, 3, sizeof(int[4]), compare);
```

Since the item type is `int[4]` then `qsort` should pass me `int(*)[4]` pointers converted to `const void*`.

So I wrote the function like this:

```c
int compare (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  const int (*ptr1)[4] = obj1;
  const int (*ptr2)[4] = obj2;
  /* ... */
  return 0;
}
```

gcc 12.2 x86 `-Wall -Wextra -std=c17 -pedantic-errors` complains about the `const int (*ptr1)[4] = obj1;` lines:

> error: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

Why am I getting this warning? There are no `const` qualifiers being discarded as far as I can tell. The type being a pointer to an array of 4 `const int`. Apparently this warning goes way back to older gcc versions too.

Whereas clang and icx with the same options compiles the same code cleanly and the end result works fine on all 3 compilers.

Comment: (If this is yet another known compiler bug I'll accept a reference to Bugzilla as the answer.)

Comment: MSVC also don't issue a warning for that.

Comment: Strangely, if you change to `-std=c2x` the warning/error goes away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That _is_ weird... I can't think of anything in the C23 draft that would be related to this, except maybe some DR that was fixed along the way..

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, intriguing :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did a bit of research and maybe it is because in C23 some standard lib functions like bsearch/qsort are now fixed to return the same type with the same qualifiers that was passed to it. Because pre-C23 they use const correctness for the parameters but return a non-qualified pointer. This might affect how qsort handles things internally. However I'm not sure why that would affect my callback function here if compiled stand-alone, outside the qsort context.

Comment: Can someone explain why he wants/needs it to be defined like the OP did: "const int (*ptr1)[4]"  and not without the [4] part?

Comment: If the OP want to have it not complaining, I would suggest:  const int (*ptr1)[4] = ( const int (*)[4] )  obj1;

Answer (score 3):

Because by passing `-pedantic-errors` you are requesting pedantic diagnostics, and, *pedantically,* `const int[4]` is not a const-qualified type (it's an array of const elements, and the array itself cannot be qualified). See [GCC bug 62198](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62198).

gcc-5.1 and newer do not issue this warning in non-pedantic mode.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm buying that explanation. Arrays cannot be qualified but array items can. In my example, the array item happens to be an array... might be a defect in 6.7.3 " If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers, the element type is so qualified, not the array type." Because they never considered that arrays may be element types, the whole "2D array" is built on this concept (formally 2D arrays don't exist). Also the gcc type system _does_ make a distinction from `const int(*)[]` and `int(*)[]`.

Comment: As for -pedantic it means "please actually be a conforming C compiler" and not "please whine about minor details". It's a very poorly chosen name.